# Symfony2 embedded form OneToMany relationship, how to persist related data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, so I hope somebody can help.

I  have a OneToMany relation between a table Resources and my FOSUserBundle provided User entity, so that one user can have posted many resources.

**Note: the entities have been edited for brevity, however I don't believe I removed anything important for this question**

My Resources entity:

```
<?php

namespace SFI\MainBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SFI\MainBundle\Entity\ResourcesRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="resources")
 */

class Resources {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */

protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */

protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */

protected $type;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */

protected $link;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */

protected $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */

protected $created_time;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SFI\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="created_by")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $created_by;

---rest of getters and setters---

    /**
     * Set created_by
     *
     * @param \SFI\UserBundle\Entity\User $createdBy
     * @return Resources
     */
    public function setCreatedBy(\SFI\UserBundle\Entity\User $createdBy = null)
    {
        $this->created_by = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created_by
     *
     * @return \SFI\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->created_by;
    }
}
```

My User entity:

```
<?php

namespace SFI\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SFI\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max="255",
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SFI\MainBundle\Entity\Resources", mappedBy="created_by")
     */
    protected $created_by;

    /**
     * Add created_by
     *
     * @param \SFI\MainBundle\Entity\Resources $createdBy
     * @return User
     */
    public function addCreatedBy(\SFI\MainBundle\Entity\Resources $createdBy)
    {
        $this->created_by[] = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove created_by
     *
     * @param \SFI\MainBundle\Entity\Resources $createdBy
     */
    public function removeCreatedBy(\SFI\MainBundle\Entity\Resources $createdBy)
    {
        $this->created_by->removeElement($createdBy);
    }

    /**
     * Get created_by
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->created_by;
    }
}
```

I have a couple of Form Types but the main one I'm working with is ResourceType:

```
<?php
namespace SFI\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ResourceType extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

    //Setting date and time
    $created_at = new \DateTime('now');

    $builder
      ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'form-control',
          'placeholder' => 'Resource name',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('type', 'choice', array(
        'required' => true,
        'empty_value' => 'Choose a type',
        'choices' => array('w' => 'Website', 'v' => 'Video', 'a' => 'Audio'),
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('link', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'form-control',
          'placeholder' => 'Add a link',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'textarea',
          'style' => 'width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;',
          'placeholder' => 'Write a description...',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('created_time', 'datetime', array(
        'disabled' => true,
        'data' => $created_at,
      ))
      ->add('save', 'submit', array(
        'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'),
      ));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'resource';
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'data_class' => 'SFI\MainBundle\Entity\Resources',
    ));
  }
}
```

My controller for the Resource form part:

```
public function resourcesAction(Request $request)
  {

      $breadcrumbs = $this->get("white_october_breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addItem("SFI Portalen", $this->get("router")->generate("sfi_static_index"));
      $breadcrumbs->addItem("Teacher Dashboard", $this->get("router")->generate("sfi_teacher_dashboard"));
      $breadcrumbs->addItem("Resources");

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $resource = new Resources();

      $newResourceForm = $this->createForm(new ResourceType(), $resource);
      $newResourceForm->handleRequest($request);

      if ($newResourceForm->isValid()) {

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        //$session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Form processed');
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Form processed, testing, no persist');

        //$em->persist($resource);
        //$em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sfi_teacher_resources'));
      }

      return $this->render('SFIMainBundle:Teacher:resources.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $newResourceForm->createView(),
      ));
  }
```

What I need to do is relate these entities when a new Resource is created, to "assign" it to the logged in user via the relation in the tables.

I've looked into embedded forms and other suggestions on Symfony's documentation, but I can't wrap my head around how to apply what I read to this specific example. I have followed the example with the tasks and the tags and the categories and all that, but I can't understand how it applies to my situation, having the User entity in another bundle, and a User form type that relates the user to their school and just adds an extra full name field, while inheriting FOSUserBundle's original form type.

I also have a funny feeling that I haven't tackled or "layed out" the relationship correctly in my code so as to make it easier to understand which objects relate.

Any help would be much appreciated! Also please let me know if you require other code or further information.

Comment: Not that this will call any errors, but using the same relation name between both entities is confusing. Consider renaming your `User` entity to have something like `resources` instead of `created_by` as a property.

Comment: I've changed that, I agree, it makes things easier. I will also change the title as there's no error right now in how I'm displaying the form, I would just like to know what more do I need in order to create a form that will persist the data with the correct relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to set the user manually before persisting the Resources entity.

```
  if ($newResourceForm->isValid()) {
    ...
    $resource->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());
    $em->persist($resource);
    $em->flush();
    ...
  }
```

Symfony makes use of the *$this->getUser()* shortcut in controllers (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object).  I'm assuming you only allow this form when the user is logged in.

Also if you are using Doctrine I would recommend using it to generate your entities and getters/setters for you, as it will generate sensible names that coincide with Symfony conventions.  For instance, your entity would end up being named 'Resource' vs. 'Resources', and your variables would be camelCased ($createdBy vs. $created_by).

Comment: I have tried this but when I persist the data, that field is missing. I will try again as I have renamed a few things. But when the query gets sent, that column field is just blank.

Comment: Just curious, what field was missing? was 'created_by' not being set in the table?

Comment: First I renamed the field itself to make it easier to relate in my brain. And the issue before was that I was passing a string (the user's id) instead of the user object. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

OK so based on Jason's suggestion, and the previous one by sjagr, I have renamed a few things for consistency and better understand, and I have written the following, which works correctly!

Thank you all for your help!

```
public function resourcesAction(Request $request)
  {

      $breadcrumbs = $this->get("white_october_breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addItem("SFI Portalen", $this->get("router")->generate("sfi_static_index"));
      $breadcrumbs->addItem("Teacher Dashboard", $this->get("router")->generate("sfi_teacher_dashboard"));
      $breadcrumbs->addItem("Resources");

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $resource = new Resource();

      $createdBy = $em->getRepository('SFIUserBundle:User')->find($this->getUser()->getId());

      $newResourceForm = $this->createForm(new ResourceType(), $resource);
      $newResourceForm->handleRequest($request);

      if ($newResourceForm->isValid()) {

        //Getting current date and time
        $created_time = new \DateTime('now');
        $resource->setCreatedTime($created_time);

        $resource->setCreatedBy($createdBy);

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Form processed');

        $em->persist($resource);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sfi_teacher_resources'));
      }

      return $this->render('SFIMainBundle:Teacher:resources.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $newResourceForm->createView(),
      ));
  }
```

All I needed was to pass the current user's entire object in **setCreatedBy** and the relation works correctly.

Thank you all again!

Comment: Hi @TuxMeister, did you try just doing `$createdBy = $this->getUser();` rather than fetching the whole entity from Doctrine?  Also, you might want to take a look at [lifecycle callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks) for handling setting createdTime to now

Comment: Yes I did try that, Jason, and it didn't like it cause that variable ends up being just a string. As for the date, I actually believe I will be forgoing that column altogether as I don't see the use for it.